# Javascript onmouseover trouble switching between img

Tags: javascript, php, html, while-loop, onmouseover

my code works, but only changes the image of the first icon when moused over. Anytime you mouse over the second or third icon, the first image is still the only one that changes.

The javascript that I am using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">

var imgdir = "category_icons/";

blank_icont = new Image;
blank_icont.src= imgdir+"blank_text.png";
addorder_icon = new Image;
addorder_icon.src = imgdir+"addorder.png";
addorder_icono = new Image;
addorder_icono.src= imgdir+"addorder2.png";
//addorder_icont = new Image;
//addorder_icont.src= imgdir+"addorder.png";

function changeImages(name) { 
document.images[name].src = eval(name + '_icono.src');
document.images.icon_text.src  = eval(name + '_icont.src');
}

function changeImages2(name){ 
document.images[name].src = eval(name + '_icon.src');
document.images.icon_text.src  = eval('blank_icont.src');
    }
</script>
```

And then the rest of my code connects to the database and you can see where I use the function `changeImages` to swap between images.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $picturepath = $row['picturepath'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $price = $row['price'];

    $dynamiclist = '<table align="center" width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8">
                        <tr height="10"><hr style="width: 60%;"></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="30% valign="top" align="left"><img style="border: #66cc33 5px solid;" src="./menupictures/'. $picturepath . '" height="140" width="140" border="1"/></td>
                            <td width="40%" valign="top" align="left"> ' . $name . ' <br /> $' . $price . ' <br /><br /><a href="moreinfo.php?id=' . $id .'">More Info</a></td>
                            <td width="30% valign="top" align="left"><a onmouseover="changeImages(&quot;addorder&quot;)" onmouseout="changeImages2(&quot;addorder&quot;)" href="customize.php?id=' . $id .'"><img id="addorder" src="category_icons
                                                                        /addorder.png" alt="" name="addorder" border="0"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>';
    echo $dynamiclist;
    }
```

To go over the problem again, the first image swaps between images when moused over, but when you hover over any other image, the first image is still the one that changes. Could it be because this is in a while loop? I've tried changing some things to get it to work, but have totally wacked out my code and don't have any idea on what is causing this? Do you have any idea?

Comment: You are looking images up by name but all your images have the same name, `addorder`. That's like yelling for "John" at the Annual John Convention.

Comment: That `eval` stuff is horrid. Use objects whose keys are the names you want to look up.

Comment: Can you show the HTML of the page, too? I'm not sure what the onmouseover code looks like in the image tags. (For example, the second and third images might accidentally be calling a function that changes the first image!)

Comment: @JonathanKuhn haha! That made me laugh. I see now. How would I work around that since it's in a while loop and creates an image for each result that is fetched from the database?

Comment: Well, each one would need it's own name. You could do something like add the id number after the name.

Comment: @BrettFromLA that is the only html. I then echo $dynamiclist;

Comment: @BrettFromLA The second code block has the html.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn & user3150191 Riiiiiiight! Thanks.  I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try add this

```
<img src="filename.extension"  id="image" onmouseover="changesrc(new_src)"/>
```

**and** add this into Script

```
function changesrc(new_src){
  var image = document.getElementById(new_src);
  image.src = "newimage.extension";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<img 
    src=<%#Eval("smallPicture","../yourfolder/{0}") %>  
    onmouseover='<%# string.Format("this.src=\"{0}\";", Eval("bigpicture","../yourfolder/{0}"))%>'
    onmouseout='<%# string.Format("this.src=\"{0}\";", Eval("smallPicture","../yourfolder/{0}"))%>'
>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation, and put the code in a code environment (put an empty line before the first code line, and indent the code by 4 spaces).